# Change the width of BootStrap Popover in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the width of BootStrap Popover. I know how to do this in the CSS file:

```
.popover{
   max-width: 800px;

}

 .popover-content {
   width:500px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

But how can I change the width in the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this, using jQuery:

```
$(".popover").css("width","500px");
```

or something like this, using plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("popover").style.width = "500px";
```